# Conjecture on different type of triangle in a complete graph?

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, conjectures

How many different triangles are there in $K_5$?

[image]

The Answer is 35.(The Moscow Mathematics Puzzle)

Then I asked what about $K_6$, $K_7$ and so on ...?

With my intuition I arrived at this conjecture

> Conjecture: The number of different triangles in a complete graph of order $n$ ($K_n$) is
>
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{n^2(n-2)^2(n-1)^2)}{6^2},&\mbox{ where } \binom{n}{3} \mbox{ is odd.}\\
> \frac{(n^2-n)(n^2-4)(n^2-5n+12)}{12^2} ,&\mbox{where }\binom{n}{3} \mbox{is even.}
> \end{cases}
>   What do you say about this?

Comment: ...what definition of "triangle" are you using where the number of triangles in $K_5$ is anything but ${5 \choose 3}$?

Comment: I think it's $K_5$ as embedded in the plane (like above). Since the number depends on the embedding, I'm also assuming some kind of standard embedding (the vertices being equally spaced along a circle).

Comment: @ albo: Why not calculate what numbers you get from your formula, and check the answers with OEIS (Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences)? ( http://oeis.org )

Comment: Different "Triangle" to mean the geometric object triangle. To Understand this take $K_4$. There are exactly $8$ different triangles in $K_4$ ; Four bigger in size and 4 smaller. Look at http://www.amazon.com/The-Moscow-Puzzles-Mathematical-Recreational/dp/0486270785

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense then.

Comment: I take it that the vertices of the triangles can be not only among the vertices  of the graph but also at any intersection of a pair of edges  of the graph, and that graph is embedded in the Euclidean plane with the edges  of the graph being line segments joining vertices of the graph

Comment: Yes, that's kind of the general consensus.

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to explain your "*intuition*" behind this conjecture. It's much easier for us to accept or reject your conjecture if we can just see the reasoning you used to reach it. Otherwise, you are really asking us to solve this problem from scratch just to see if you are right or wrong.

Comment: Explaining intuition sounds like a contradiction in terms.